# How to use the Tabs module?

Tags: 7

I've installed the Tabs module, but I don't know how to use it.

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're talking about **[tabs](http://drupal.org/project/tabs)**

As it is written on the page :

> The tabs module integrates the jQuery UI tabs plugin, providing client-side interactive tabs. This is a helper module. It doesn't do anything on its own. **Rather, it is used by other modules that provide tabs.**

If you are not a coder, don't use this module.
If there is not any module that ask you to install this module, don't use this module.

If you want some tabs to break long pages into smaller ones, have a look on **[paging](http://drupal.org/project/paging)** module.

If you just want to add some tabs like "Views," "Edit," etc on nodes, this is handled by core code; have a look to the **[API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal)**, especially **[hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu/6)**.

Answer (score 1):

Tabs module does not do much on its own.
I suggest you to look at [Views tabs](http://drupalmodules.com/module/views-tabs); this is an awesome module that groups page templates created by [Views](http://drupalmodules.com/module/views).
It works like this:

1. You create a view with many page templates
2. You go to Site Setting  -> Views Tabs module administration page and select the pages of a view you want to be displayed in tabs.

I know this is a very short explanation; it just covers the general concepts.

Comment: I'm sure you don't understand what I want.

Comment: How can I make tabs in a page. I know how to install modules